# How can I remove complete hashtags from my output

Tags: javascript

I am using the JavaScript project, `Instafeed.js` to output an Instagram profile onto my website.

The project allows you to create HTML templates using a moustache style template.

I want to remove all hashtags from the Instagram posts's caption.

Here is the code on my webpage. In `Instafeed.js` Instagram feed options are referenced using `{{image}}`, `{{timestamp}}`. `{{caption}}`, etc...

Everything worked fine until I started trying to remove the hashtags with regexp.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var feed = new Instafeed({
      accessToken: InstagramToken,
      limit: 10,
      target: 'instafeed2',
      transform: function(item) { //Transform receives each item as its argument
    // Over-write the original timestamp
    item.timestamp = new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleString('en-AU', {
        weekday: 'long', 
        year: 'numeric', 
        month: 'long', 
        day: 'numeric'
      });

    // return the modified item
    return item;
   
  },

  

transform: function(item) { //Transform receives each item as its argument
    // Over-write the original timestamp
    item.caption = new (item.caption),
        regexp = /\#\w\w+\s?/g,
        item.caption = item.caption.replace(regexp, '')
        
      

    // return the modified item
    return item;
  },
      template: '<div class="parent-container"><div class="post-title">{{timestamp}}</div><div class="vertical-line"></div> <div class="post-container">   <div class="post-image"><img src="{{image}}"/></div> <div class="post-description">{{caption}}</div>     </div>     <div class="vertical-line"></div>    </div>',
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression :

```
const caption = 'asdasd #hashtag1 asdasdasd ascxzc.#hashtag2 asd asd asd #hashtag3,#hashtag4 asdads'
const regexp = new RegExp('#([^\\s]*)','g');
console.log(caption.replace(regexp, '').replace(/  +/g, ' '));
```